# How to configure PHP server variable $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?

Tags: php, webserver

We have PHP programs that use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] as a path to a place where we can place a private directory (using a unique name) in a safe, known place on server.   This directory holds data summaries collected from multiple perhaps thousands of served PHP pages; this summary has no impact on the main functionality of the pages served, and eventually can be ignored or deleted.  While it exists, a PHP-based tool can inspect the summary data and provide a report.

This has worked well on a variety of PHP servers, and appears to be "automatically" (?) set according to the [PHP Manual documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'
>
> ```
>    The document root directory under which the current script
>    is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.
> ```

We installed several different PHP servers over the years, and they all seem to come with this pre-configured to a reasonable path without any explicit configuration effort on our part.

We have some clients using our software that complain that this path seems to be set to null, which seems inconsistent with the above definition.  (Does null signify some special path?)

Pardon my ignorance, but is this a configurable item?  Where do I find the server "configuration file" for this? Is it the same place for all different PHP server implementations?  Can I/should I change that configuration files to set this explicitly if it is not set?

If not, is there another way to provide a path to a safe long-term "temporary" local directory?

Comment: A)programming questions normally go on stackoverflow

Comment: I thought this was a configuration question.

Comment: B)I'm no expert but from my limited experience I haven't used anything that calls itself a "php server". I've used Apache which is a web server and that supports php.  Precisely what web server are you using?  Many people don't just install PHP alone(if that can be done, I haven't seen it done, though I haven't seen much), but I have installed WAMP (includes apache and its php support).. So in that case the configuration file would be within Apache. Apache makes an icon in the taskbar you can right click  and look at configuration files

Comment: that may be an argument against posting to SO,.. though I've seen programming IDE questions go on stackoverflow.. And i've sure there are many questions on e.g. configuring the java virtual machine classpath variable that are on SO not SU.

Comment: @barlop:  "php server" is my phrase; I intened to to mean any Windows/PHP engine or  LAMP/WAMP stack or anything else that can serve out PHP pages.   Our client claims they have  (php -v) "PHP 5.6.16-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)
... Zend Engine v2.6.0, ...    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, ..."   No, I haven't gotten a clear description of OS or whether they are running Apache.  And I'm a rank amatuer at configuring PHP servers.

Comment: @barlop: I'd be pleased to post this question anywhere that maximizes its chances of getting answered.  I thought configuration questions was one of SU's specialties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46814/discussion-between-barlop-and-ira-baxter).

Comment: Learned which OS:  (uname -or): "3.19.0-25-generic GNU/Linux"

Comment: @barlop:  Asked at SO, and as you predicted, got useful information pretty fast.  Thanks for redirecting me.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/40048444/120163